# Random Walk Problem(Escape Recursion)

Tags: python, oop, random, recursion

As practice, and as a precursor to a more complex, larger project I have in mind, I have created a random walk script using the Turtle module. I realize that there are simpler ways to do the random walk without having to find the neighboring coordinates, but as far as I can tell this is necessary for the larger implementation.

The problem I am having is that python is reaching its maximum recursion depth when it finds that it has visited every adjacent cell in the `getnext()` function. I'm not sure how I would escape that loop and continue on as normal should that occur.

```
import turtle
import random




class cell(object):
def __init__(self, pos, visited = False):
    self.xCoord = pos[0]
    self.yCoord = pos[1]
    self.visited = visited
    self.neigh = []
    self.neighbors = self.getneighbors()

def getneighbors(self):
    for j in (-1, 0, 1):
        for i in (-1, 0, 1):
            self.neigh.append((self.xCoord+i, self.yCoord+j))



def getnext():
   nextindex = random.randint(0, len(c.neigh)-1)
   nextcoordt = c.neigh[nextindex]
   nextcoord = list(c.neigh[nextindex])
   if nextcoordt in coords:
       getnext()
   else:
      turtle.goto(nextcoord[0], nextcoord[1])



coords = {} 

turtle.setup(width =200, height = 200, startx = 0, starty = 0)
turtle.trace = False

for i in range(1000):
    c = cell(list(turtle.pos()))
    coords[turtle.pos()] = (c)
    getnext()
```

Furthermore this is actually my first true application of OOP and I was wondering if this was a good way to use it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your random walk finds that it has visited every adjacent cell, it would loop forever. Since you're using recursion it quickly exceeds the maximum recursion limit.

I'm sure this could be written in an OOP way, but the problems are more in your use of recursion than whether the `cell` class is useful.  For example, I've simplified your code to run in a linear fashion.  The changes are:

- Eliminate the (0, 0) direction since it makes no forward progress. (optional depending on your goal, i.e. if you consider "staying put" a valid move or not).
- Uses `random.choice()` to pick the direction of the next move.
- Removes recursion in favor of calculating the next coordinate by adding the direction vector to the current position. A simple loop suffices.
- Doesn't check the next position against a recent history of positions, since a move back to a previous space is perfectly valid for randomness.

Code:

```
import itertools
import random
import turtle

# change step size if you like
STEP = 1
PTS = [-STEP, 0, STEP]
DIRS = [(x, y) for x in PTS for y in PTS if x or y]

turtle.setup(width=400, height=400, startx=0, starty=0)
turtle.trace = False
pos = turtle.pos()

for i in range(1000):
    px, py = turtle.pos()
    # direction of next move
    xd, yd = random.choice(DIRS)
    # set pos to current pos + direction vector
    turtle.goto(px + xd, py + yd)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My reason for using a cell class is that I am trying to make a rudimentary drawing robot that will bruteforce trace a potentially curvy path, that doesn't have a set width, in an image file. For example a filled black circle on a white background. My intent is to get the color value of each of the current coords neighbors and move to a given coord depending on the color. Thus, I thought it would be easy to have a class with an attribute for color, which I haven't added yet of course... Is my approach even remotely correct/feasible? haha

Comment: It sounds sort of like [region growing](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Region_growing) which you'll find in image editing software. You select an initial seed pixel and then grow the selection by selecting adjacent pixels whose color is the same or similar to your seed (within some threshold). This is typically done by a scan of all adjacent pixels, but I see no reason why you couldn't incorporate some weighting for color into your random walk.

Comment: Well when you say "but I see no reason why you couldn't incorporate some weighting for color into your random walk" do you mean the one I wrote, or your version? I was planning on doing that eventually, but I wanted to get the basic functionality down first. The concept I am having difficulty grasping is if I do indeed use OOP for this, and I have a class with a color attribute, would that mean at every step i would need to declare 5( or 9 if I include diagonals) objects? I am not proficient enough with data structures I feel to accomplish this procedurally. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I meant "I see no reason why.." in general; it just applies to how the color is used to choose the next position.  You could certainly represent the pixels as objects if you like, I see no problem with it. There are more efficient ways, but while you're learning Python I wouldn't worry about efficiency: just focus on getting the correct algorithm. You can also ask more questions on SO if you get stuck. :-)  Good luck!

Comment: Alright thanks alot! I really appreciate the help. I do always get the feeling that people dislike it when someone asks another question when it somewhat relates to the same topic/ project... D: If thats not the case however, I will gladly pick all of the knowledgable brains here. Thanks Again! :D